# Does the server edition support at least 8 cores in SMP mode?

Tags: server, kernel

I am in the process of buying dual-Xeon (each 4 core) server grade machine for our Android build server requirement, for my team at my work place.  Could you please confirm that the Ubuntu server version that is used for Android build environment supports at least 8 processors in SMP mode.  I did some reading and saw that it supports up to 8 cores without any recompilation; please confirm this.

I just want to make sure that we use the full potential of the Xeon processor while running ubuntu on it and build our applications and the SW stacks faster. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this launchpad answer *from 2007*](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/9820), the limits are  32 cores for 32bit and 64 cores  for 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question directly, but I have been happily using 11.04 on x64 Xeon 4-processor workstations with all the cores working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Eight cores shouldn't be any problems.

At work we have nodes with dual hexa-cores running hyperthreaded, exposing 24 "cores" to the OS. That works fine with recents Ubuntu kernels as well as rather old Debian kernels.